# passing a pointer as a parameter to a function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to wrap my head around how pointers work in functions.

I have the understanding that pointers can be used as function parameters like so

```c
int *max(int* a, int* b){
    if (*a > *b)
      return a;
    else
      return b;
}

int *p, i, j;
p = max(&i, &j);
```

Now my understanding of this is that I have a function that returns an int pointer, and its parameters are 2 int pointers. When the function is called, it is supplied with the address of 2 int types, i and j, which the pointers in the parameters are assigned to respectively. In the end, the large int is returned. Is this correct? To me, that makes sense.

I am confused with what is happening when a pointer is passed to a function instead.

So, something like

```c
int *p, i, j;
int *k = &i
p = max(k, &j);
```

Is a copy of the pointer made instead in this case? Furthermore, how would this work with objects? Would an entire object a pointer pointed to be copied, or would just the pointer be?

Comment: You would need to initialize `i` and `j` in your example, otherwise they have indeterminate values. `k` (which holds the address of `i`) is copied into `a` and `a` or `b` is copied into `p` upon return. `p` now holds the address of either `i` or `j`.

Comment: `max` returns a pointer, not a large int. Avoid the mistake of conflating a pointer with the thing it points to, in your mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially an assignment (not the assignment operation `a = b`, but behaves identically).

When you pass an argument to a function, you are essentially making an assignment from the argument to the function parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int *param)
{
    return *param + 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int var = 0;
    int *pointer = &var;
    
    printf("This will print 1: %d\n", foo(&var));
    printf("This will also print 1: %d\n", foo(pointer));
}
```

When you make the first call, it works as if you were making the assignment `param = &var`, which is totally fine, because you are making the variable `param` in the function `foo` receive the address of `var`.

When you make the second call, it works as if you were making the assignment `param = pointer`, which is also totally fine, because you are making the variable `param` in the function `foo` receive the value of `pointer`, which is also the address of `var`.

The best way to view pointers is to think of them just as variables like `int`s, `char`s, etc. Pointers are not really that special, they are just variables that holds values. But instead of that value being an integer, or a floating-point number, it's a memory address.

Comment: It is literally assignment; C 2018 6.5.2.2 4 says “… In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Quick related question (or shall I post as a formal question?): As an example, with `double sqrt(double x); ... sqrt(0.1f)`, would you agree the _argument_ has the value/type of `0.1f`,`float` and the _parameter_ has the value/type/address of `0.1....`, `double`, `&x`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, `0.1f` is the argument and has type `float`. C 2018 3.3 defines argument as “expression in the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses in a function call expression, or [something else for macros]”. 6.5.2.2 6 refers to “the arguments after promotion,” so that indicates you might consider a `double` resulting from a `float` argument to be an argument, but that is largely an artifact of language rather than intentional definition. And I do not see a corresponding use for conversion due to prototype, rather than default promotion…

Comment: … A parameter is an object, so, if `sqrt` is implemented in C, its parameter is an object with type `double`.

Answer (score 2):

> … when a pointer is passed to a function instead.

The code `max(k, &j)` does not pass anything different from `max(&i, &j)`.

`&i` is a value. It is the address of `i`. After `int *k = &i;`, the value of `k` is `&i`. Using the value of `k` and using `&i` are the same thing.

`max(k, &j)` is the same thing as `max(&i, &j)`.

> In the end, the large int is returned. Is this correct?

No, the function returns the address of the larger `int`. It does not return an `int`.

> Is a copy of the pointer made instead in this case?

Every argument passed to a function is copied. If you call `foo(3)`, a copy of the `int` 3 is made. If you call `foo(&i)`, a copy of the address of `i` is made. If you call `foo(k)`, a copy of the value of `k` is made, regardless of whether `k` is an `int`, a pointer to an `int`, or something else.

One thing that may confuse people new to C is that `foo("abc")` converts the string to a pointer to its first element first. Then a copy of that pointer is passed to `foo`. The string is not copied. This is not special to function calls; it happens whenever an array is used in an expression except as an operand of `sizeof`, as an operand of unary `&`, or as a string literal used to initialize an array.

Comment: And with C23, the exception will also be there if it's an operand of `typeof` or an operand of `typeof_unqual`.

Comment: I first thought so too but 2 responses from those questions lead me to think otherwise.